# How to store and render an html in React?

Tags: reactjs

I use a standard html rich text editor in my backend, and it's stored in MongoDB with all tags and other staff. It's a simple MERN project with CRUD functionality.
HTML is stored in the "content" field.
But when I pass it through a props to my React component, in a browser I see an html with all the tags, not the "right" text.
How to do it properly in React?

The Post component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <h3>{this.props.longTitle}</h3>
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

The Posts rendered here:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Post from "./Post";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import AddService from "./AddService";

class Services extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      services: [],
      loading: true,
      error: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("services");
    axios.get('http://localhost:5555/services')
      .then(res => {
        const services = res.data;
        this.setState({ services, loading: false });        
      })
      .catch(err => { // log request error and prevent access to undefined state
        this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
        console.error(err);
      })
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p> Loading... </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (this.state.error || !this.state.services) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p> An error occured </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="center">
          <h2 className="underline">Добавить сервис</h2>
          <img src={require("../img/orn.png")} alt="" className="orn" />
        </div>
        <AddService />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Link to="/services">
            <h2 className="center">Сервисы</h2>
          </Link>
          <br />
          <div className="center">
            <img src={require("../img/orn.png")} alt="" className="orn" />
          </div>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/services"
              render={() => <Home services={this.state.services} />}
            />
            <Route
              path="/services/:_id"
              render={props => {
                const _id = props.match.params._id;
                const data = this.state.services.find(item => item._id == _id);
                if (data) {
                  return <Post {...props} {...data} />;
                }
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.services.map(post => (
          <h3>
            <Link to={`/services/${post._id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
          </h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Services;
```

What is the right way?
Thanks to everyone!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, using `react-render-html` package.

first install it to your dependencies: `npm install react-render-html`

Then: your in `Post` component, supposing that `this.props.content` is a string that contains the HTML you want to render:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <h3>{this.props.longTitle}</h3>
        {renderHTML(this.props.content)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: I am so Glad, REACT IS MY GIRLFRIEND :D - Make sure you kindly mark this answer as - Correct Answer - so other users with the same case of question have an idea where to go for a solution. Good luck Kiten!

Comment: @kiten you should accept the solution, click on checkbox in order to close question.